# how to change color of QGraphicsEllipseItem when it selected?

Tags: python, colors, pyqt, selection

i use python 2.7 + pyqt4.8

i create many items like `QGraphicsEllipseItem` and `QGraphicsRectItem` in my scene. I made them all different colors. the allocation of the elements around them appears bounding rect, and I would like that they also changed the fill color to another color (white). When removing the selection to return to the original color.

how to change color of `QGraphicsEllipseItem` when it selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trigger your `QGraphicsEllipseItem` "clicked" signal with a handler method which we call it here `ellipseClickHandler` where you change the color of your ellipse item by calling its setBrush method like this for instance:

```
def ellipseClickHandler(self, ellipseItem)
    ellipseItem.setBrush(QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red, style = QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
```