# pyqt4 / linux /RPi : CPU usage slowly increases to > 100%

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt4, raspberry-pi3, cpu-usage

I am building a Python3 / PyQt4 app that runs on a Raspberry Pi and communicates with a device over the serial port.

The serial port runs in its own thread. To send messages to the device, a Queue() is used. Each second a timer in the GUI puts a number of messages onto the queue. The serial thread processes them one by one, with timeout and retries, and when a valid response is received, signal/slots are used to notify the GUI (in the main thread).

The problem I have is that CPU usage (monitored with top) increases slowly over time, eventually rising well over 100% (I've seen around 150-170% after an hour or so). There is a while(True) loop in the serial thread; adding a bit of sleep time (say 10-50ms) to it reduces CPU usage overall, but the same behaviour still occurs eventually.

Oddly enough if I run the app but never start the Timer (so no serial comms occurs), CPU usage sits constantly at around 100%.

I've tried using strace, it tells me that a lot of time is spent in futex (30-50%) but I never see anything getting up to around the 100% mark.

**EDIT:**
It turned out that my problem had pretty much nothing to do with serial comms, threading, or QTimer(). I eventually found out that it was due to my abuse of objects in the GUI. I have posted the cause of the issue in my answer below. Because of this I have also removed the smaple code here which in fact was not part of the cause.

Comment: Hi! I think this will be very hard to debug without a [mcve]. Especially since you've indicated the problem changes when you don't start the `QTimer`, but you haven't included the code for that part. Could you produce a cut down version of your entire application, that still reproduces the problem, and update your question?

Comment: Hi  - thank you for the feedback. Yes, I will certainly do that - it will be in the next few days as I cannot attend to it immediately. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When I went through the process of stripping down a copy of the code to find the cause, the answer in fact had little to do with threading or serial comms.

In my GUI I have some simple objects which subclass QGraphicsView and draw circles (in fact it is a mimic of an LED to indicate good/bad comms activity).

When I wanted to change colour of the circle, I was in fact again calling drawEllipse() in the object. To make matters worse, this was happening multiple times per second. (A nasty way of doing things that I did when initially "mocking up" the project.) So the cure was twofold:

1. restructure code to only set LED status twice per second (once when starting to query device registers, once when done)
2. use the correct method of changing LED colour as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650301/how-to-change-color-of-qgraphicsellipseitem-when-it-selected)

With these fixes in place CPU usage remains stable at around 40% (and the code is much cleaner).